# JS button, increment/decrement not working on input field correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an issue getting the javascript increase/decrease buttons on my site to work. When I declare my JS variable as the class name of my input field, if I hit the button it increases/decreases all of the input fields like this:

[image]

However, when I use the ID of my input field, it increases/decreases the first row, but the buttons on all of the other buttons don't work. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. The JS is obviously working but how can I get it to work for each row/button respectively.

The html of my laravel blade:

```
@foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
<tr>
<td>
  <div>
  <button id="subtract" class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
  <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0'  />
  <button id="add" class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success"  style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
  </div>
  </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
```

And my JS:

```
@section('loadjs')
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/pagination.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/bower_components/uikit/js/components/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/factory.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#add").click(function(){
var value = $(".md-input").val();
value = +value + 1;
$(".md-input").val(value);
});

$("#subtract").click(function(){
var value = $(".md-input").val();
value = +value - 1;
$(".md-input").val(value);
});
</script>
@endsection
```

As you can see, my JS code is currently using the class of my input field which is making one button affect all input fields.

How can I rectify this to work correctly?

UPDATE: New Code that I'm attempting:

Html:

```
<div>
<button class="subtract" class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
<input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
<button class="add" class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
</div>
```

JS:

```
@section('loadjs')
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/pagination.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/bower_components/uikit/js/components/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/factory.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".add").click(function() {
  var inputField = $(this).prev('input'), /* get the input field */
      value = parseInt( inputField.val() ); /* get its value and parse it as integer */
  value += 1; /* add one */
  inputField.val(value); /* put the value back */
});

$(".subtract").click(function() {
  var inputField = $(this).next('input'),
      value = parseInt( inputField.val() );
  value -= 1;
  inputField.val(value);
});
</script>
@endsection
```

Comment: You can't have multiple `id`s on a page, the should be unique. Rather use classes!

Comment: You should link every id's (buttons and field) with suffix quantity_id so that every id is different and you can use the quantity_id to decide which field to update

Comment: Well the JS is currently using classes, but when I hit the add/minus button on the first row it adds or subtracts to all input fields on the page? Also, the first row of buttons are the only buttons that work

Comment: @Ko2r how exactly do you mean though?

Comment: `id="subtract_{{ $psku->quantity_id }}"` Something like this. And then in the click handler, you can retrieve the quantity_id and update the right field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have some error in your code: first of all you can not have multiple time the same id, you can use classes for this kind of thing... moreover I suggest you to add a class to the containing div, handling the events from that in order to be always sure what and where you are incrementing/decrementing and in order to have less listener in you script

```js
@section('loadjs')
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/pagination.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/bower_components/uikit/js/components/slider.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/factory.js') }}"></script>
<script src="{{ jfi\asset_cb('/js/jquery.min.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.incrementer-class-name').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $input = $this.find('.md-input');
  $this.on('click', '.add-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(++val);
  }).on('click', '.remove-button', function() {
    var val = parseInt($input.val());
    $input.val(--val);
  });
});
</script>
@endsection
```

```html
@foreach ($pgroup->pskus as $psku)
<tr>
  <td>
    <div class="incrementer-class-name">
      <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
      <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
      <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
    </div>
  </td>
</tr>
  @endforeach
```

Comment: glad to be helpful :)

Answer (score 3):

As already commented, you should have unique id's on a page.

So rather change `id="add"` to `class="id"`.

I've updated the function, see the comments in the code for some explanation.

```js
$(".add-button").click(function() {
  var inputField = $(this).prev('input'), /* get the input field */
      value = parseInt( inputField.val() ); /* get its value and parse it as integer */
  value += 1; /* add one */
  inputField.val(value); /* put the value back */
});

$(".remove-button").click(function() {
  var inputField = $(this).next('input'),
      value = parseInt( inputField.val() );
  value -= 1;
  inputField.val(value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <button class="remove-button md-btn" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">remove</i></button>
        <input type="text" class="md-input" id="{{ $psku->quantity_id }}" name="count" onClick="this.setSelectionRange(0, this.value.length);" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; margin: 0; text-align: center; height: 30px;" value='0' />
        <button class="add-button md-btn md-btn-success" style="width: 33%; min-width: 0; float: left; height: 30px;"><i class="material-icons">add</i></button>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Your snippet works perfectly but it's not working for me for some reason. I will post an update block of my code real quick

Comment: Ok I updated my original question with the new version based on your answer. For some reason now no buttons are working

Comment: I just noticed that my code contained two `class` attributes :$. That might be part of the problem, please see the updated answer and try the code again

Comment: Hmm still no dice for some reason. Could it have anything to do with my foreach loop